# NURBS surfaces in OpenGL 3.2 core profile

Tags: opengl-3, glu, nurbs

Is it possible to draw NURBS (Non-uniform rational B-spline) surfaces in OpenGL 3.2 core profile?

I assume that the NURBS rendering using GLU library does not support the core profile.

Is there any open source libraries that implement the same functionality as GLU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GLU with core profiles from OpenGL 3.1 onwards, won't really work.  GLU is layered on top of a many deprecated OpenGL functions, and your application most likely won't either link or work correctly.

As for NURBS implementation in GLU, the source code is available in the open source from SGI at http://oss.sgi.com/projects/ogl-sample/.  You could probably fix the library to use more modern OpenGL methods.

Also more details are given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993486/what-about-nurbs-and-opengl-4-2-core/14431206#14431206).

Comment: I actually ended up implementing my own NURBS library https://github.com/mortennobel/OpenGL_3_2_Utils The library is a bit more OO than GLU.